# Showing validation errors at top of page with PHP

Tags: php, forms, validation

I've written a Form object (code: http://pastebin.com/U1xMRhdn) that validates whether information entered in a form field is valid or not. An example of it:

```
<?php
$f = Form(...);
//I would like to output the amount of errors up here.
$f->textBox(...);
$f->radioArea(...);
if($f->getErrors()>0)
    echo "You have "+$f->getErrors();+" errors, go back and try again";
?>
```

If the user didn't enter anything into the textbox the error counter increments.
The problem: I would like to display how many errors the user got wrong on top of the page. However, when I tried doing this the error counter retrieved 0 errors because the items had not yet been validated in functions `textBox` and `radioArea`. Is there a way to capture a value at the end of the script and return it to the top of the script? Or do I have to find another way of counting the errors?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using output buffers on the index.php page that contains the implementation of the code.

Comment: I think it's better to validate if the `textbox` is empty on the client-side (since you want to display this error to the user).

Comment: Not necessarily, what if the user has javascript turned off?

Comment: You **must** validate server-side, you can optionally choose to validate client side. **"Always validate your inputs"**

Comment: It would be better for your Form class to return the output, rather than echo. Then you can choose when to output it.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen right. but for the purpose of displaying error input to the user-  it's better to do it on the client side. Later on, you'll have to re-validate the same input on the server-side - but this have nothing to do with displaying errors to the user.

Comment: @GlennDayton then the user probably can't browse 99.9% of the websites... :)

Comment: @alfasin I would be more concerned about just the average "user". Hackers could easily exploit a site without server-side validation. Without server-side validation inputted data could also be non-uniformal. Someone could enter HTML into a box that is strictly raw text. The `Form` object that I wrote doesn't have those features, but they are implemented later in the code.

Comment: @GlennDayton did you hear me say anything against server-side validation ??? All I'm saying is: when you want to display errors to the user about incorrect input, it's better to do it on the client side. I wouldn't *submit* a form just to display these errors. The server-side validations are mandatory - but you can do them later on in your code, it doesn't have to be on the same page. Checkout the following page for example, try to submit it without filling-out the form: https://sandbox.plimus.com/jsp/buynow.jsp?contractId=2113948

Comment: @alfasin Nah, I guess I didn't have my speakers turned up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using *output buffers*?

Like so:

```
<?php
ob_start(); // start buffering
$f = Form(...);
//I would like to output the amount of errors up here.
$f->textBox(...);
$f->radioArea(...);
$form_html = ob_get_clean(); // end the buffer, get it, and clean it
if($f->getErrors()>0)
    echo "You have "+$f->getErrors();+" errors, go back and try again";
echo $form_html;
?>
```

Comment: Alright I will try this. I'm using buffers on the page that instantiates that Form object, but I think I need to do this as well.

Answer (score 0):

use a get data  req and spit the answer back at the div of ure choice. every time the user inputs something the ajax will call the php if therer is an error, the answer will be ajaxed in. you can use on key pressed if you want the validation to run everytime there is a keystroke in the textarea